Can we really be sure that there is no odd perfect number below $10^{3000}$?
A positive integer $N$ is called perfect if the sum of its divisors (including $1$ and $N$) is $2N$. A famous open problem is whether there is an odd perfect number.

Can someone confirm the following result of the german Wikipedia article about possible odd perfect numbers ?

Sollte sie kleiner als 10 9118 {\displaystyle 10^{9118}} sein, dann ist sie durch p 6 {\displaystyle p^{6}} teilbar mit einer Primzahl p {\displaystyle p}, die größer als 10 500 {\displaystyle 10^{500}$} ist.
Translation in English : If a perfect odd number $N$ satisfies $N<10^{9118}$ , then there is a prime number $p>10^{500}$ with $p^6\mid N$.
This explains that it is also claimed that a perfect odd number must be greater than $10^{3000}$ since this is an easy consequence of this result.
The english Wikpedia article mentions just $10^{1500}$ and nothing comparable strong with the above result. The above result would make it almost sure that $10^{9118}$ is a lower bound , but it rather looks like a typo (maybe $10^{50}$ instead of $10^{500}$?)
I think , something has been mixed up. If not , I would like to know a source confirming it.

here is the german wikipedia article.

I'd love to check for you, but I'm busy the next eternity.

Can such questions not be posted here anymore ? Which context is expected in cases like this ?

It's partially correct, see On the Divisibility of an Odd Perfect Number by the Sixth Power of a Prime by McDaniel from 1971.
In short, if $N<10^{9118}$ then we are only guaranteed existence of a prime $p$ such that $p^6\mid N$, without any restrictions on $p$. The condition $p>10^{500}$ does not align with McDaniel's findings and should be reconsidered. I suggest removing that condition from the wiki article and adding proper source to make the claim justified (since I don't speak German I leave this to others).
By the way this proofwiki's article has the claim stated correctly.
Note: This is not the only problem in the article, it also incorrectly claims $N>10^{3000}$ in the first bullet and references source that itself cites old result $N>10^{300}$ and proves $N>10^{1500}$.
